# gulp-cache AssertionError: missing path

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin, gulp-cached

this is my gulpfile.js

```
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();    

    // Optimize images
        gulp.task('images', function () {
          return gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
            .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
              progressive: true,
              interlaced: true
            })))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
            .pipe($.size({title: 'images'}));
        });
```

[image]